# Is it possible to extract audio from soundcloud-widget

Tags: reactjs, soundcloud, http-live-streaming, p5.js, m3u8

I have a p5 canvas that makes visuals accords to the song it plays.

I try to add SoundCloud-widget as another music resource for user (and not just local uploading).

Are there is a way to extract the audio/blob/m3u8 from the widget? just set the display of the widget to "none" it is not enough because the song not going through p5 canvas.

The widget sends the music in HLS protocol, however when getting into network tab and filter for m3u8 couldn't find anything.

Right now I've got from

---

```
 widget.getCurrentSound(currentSound => {
      console.log(currentSound)
    }
```

---

in my console -

---

```
artwork_url: 'https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000217481049-b5k347-large.jpg'
comment_count: 1412
commentable: true
created_at: "2017-04-12T16:00:36Z"
description: ""
display_date: "2017-04-12T16:00:36Z"
domain_lockings: []
download_count: 0
download_url: null
downloadable: false
duration: 262710
embeddable_by: "all"
full_duration: 262710
genre: "Deep House"
has_downloads_left: true
id: 317363228
kind: "track"
label_name: null
last_modified: "2019-08-02T11:58:38Z"
license: "cc-by"
likes_count: 29882
media: {transcodings: Array(2)}
monetization_model: "NOT_APPLICABLE"
permalink: "mysong"
permalink_url: "https://soundcloud.com/...."
playable: true
playback_count: 1549676
policy: "ALLOW"
public: true
publisher_metadata: {urn: "soundcloud:tracks:XXXXXX", artist: "... ", id: 111111111}
purchase_title: "Free Download !"
purchase_url: null
release_date: null
reposts_count: 3378
secret_token: null
sharing: "public"
state: "finished"
streamable: true
tag_list: "my song""
title: "my song"
uri: "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/11111"
urn: "soundcloud:tracks:3111111"
user: {soundcloud user obj}
user_id: 11111111
visuals: null
waveform_url: "https://wave.sndcdn.com/XXXXXXX.json"
_resource_id: 11111111
_resource_type: "sound"  
__proto__: Object
```

---

Thanks in advance :)